# Как вставлять в базу данных данные которых там еще нет

Tags: python, mysql

```
names = [item["nick"] for item in data["moderators"]]
discord_u = [item["user_id"] for item in data["moderators"]]
vk_m = [item["vk"] for item in data["moderators"]]
x = {
    'nick': names,
    'user_id': discord_u,
    'vk': vk_m
}
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="",
        user="",
        password="",
        database="",
        )
curs = mydb.cursor()
for i in range(len(names)):
        sql = 'SELECT id FROM moderator WHERE id = discord_u'
        if sql is None:
            sqlFormula = 'INSERT INTO moderator (id, coins, nick, warns, VK) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
            values = (discord_u[i], 0, names[i], 0, vk_m[i])
            curs.execute(sqlFormula, values)      
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
names = [item["nick"] for item in data["moderators"]]
discord_u = [item["user_id"] for item in data["moderators"]]
vk_m = [item["vk"] for item in data["moderators"]]
x = {
    'nick': names,
    'user_id': discord_u,
    'vk': vk_m
}
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="",
        user="",
        password="",
        database="",
        )
curs = mydb.cursor()
for i in range(len(names)):
        curs.execute('SELECT * FROM moderator WHERE id = %s', (discord_u,))
        sql = curs.fetchall()
        if len(sql)<1:
            sqlFormula = 'INSERT INTO moderator (id, coins, nick, warns, VK) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
            values = (discord_u[i], 0, names[i], 0, vk_m[i])
            curs.execute(sqlFormula, values)
            mydb.commit()
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: curs.execute('SELECT id FROM moderator WHERE id = %s', (discord_u))
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: Исправил, попробуйте сейчас. curs.execute('SELECT * FROM moderator WHERE id = %s', (discord_u))

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: а у вас как таблица называется в бд? вы вообще ее создали?

Comment: moderator, данные внесены

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/jD5rnL3

Comment: хм. попробуйте сейчас

Comment: Такая же ошибка возникает.

Comment: ладно, тогда я сдаюсь

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример решения:

```
import pymysql

mydb = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                user='root',
                                password='',
                                database='ggg',
                                cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
curs = mydb.cursor()
discord_u = input("discord: ")
names = input("names: ")
vk_m = input("vk_m: ")
sql = f"SELECT id FROM moderator WHERE id = '{discord_u}' AND nick = '{names}' AND vk = '{vk_m}'"
curs.execute(sql) 
result = curs.fetchall()
print(len(result))
        
if len(result) == 0:
    with mydb:
        with mydb.cursor() as cursor:
                        
            sqlFormula = 'INSERT INTO moderator (id, coins, nick, warns, VK) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
            curs.execute(sqlFormula, (discord_u, 0, names, 0, vk_m)) 
        mydb.commit()     
else:
    pass
```

Comment: и что мне это дает?
По-моему я описал суть проблемы в заголовке, вы же скидываете как вставлять данные в базу данных.

Comment: то есть вы хотите вставить данные при условии что в базе данных нет уже таких данных? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Если данных в базе нет, он их вставит если они есть то их всталять не нужно

Comment: Все равно не понимаю(

Comment: какие именно данные не должны повторяться?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/kR1zIM1

Comment: вот так должно работать

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '} AND nick = {names} AND vk = {vk_m}' at line 1

Comment: Добавь f перед select, сори вылетело из головы

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '['281399948321488896', '479252728221270037', '484741815573151773', '599671998...' at line 1

Comment: ох уж этот sql, Поставь всю коменду в двойные кавычки, а перед фигурными скобками единичные сейчас исправлю

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '281399948321488896', '479252728221270037', '484741815573151773', '59967199820...' at line 1

Comment: Должно помочь, но если нет то без базы данных помочь, к сожалению не смогу

Comment: Могу дать таблицу

Comment: давай, ты пользуешься PyMySQL?

Comment: sql = f"SELECT id FROM moderator WHERE id = `discord_u` AND nick = `names` AND vk = `vk_m`"
Если делать так.
Выдает данную ошибку
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'discord_u' in 'where clause'
в ошибке и написано что не так
что не найдена колонка discord_u

Comment: Да я подумал смысл давать таблицу, если у меня информацию берет с сайта, так что толку не будет

Comment: sql = f"SELECT * FROM moderator WHERE id = id"
Если делать что-то подобное он вставляет только первую строчку c json

Comment: Я сделал простую базу данных с одной таблицей и код который я выше написал работает, но если ты используешь не pymysql то помочь сильно не смогу